# MVC app runs locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So for a while I have been uploading just fine to the server and my solution has worked..client has created a new server and now when uploading my solution to the server to be hosted by iis it gives an error and is looking for a file in Models but the path to that file is the path I use on my local machine where the solution is stored eg: d:\work\client

Why is it trying to find that when I have uploaded the bin directory with the solution, surely it should look for the model in the bin directory?

Comment: Please can you post the error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the way I was publishing, previously I would literally copy and paste the files over to the server, but I must have been missing something.  Doing a publish from within visual studio worked.